# Avoid inline styling - Mui V5

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

In my opinion seperating styling from code makes the code clearer and cleaner. Using inline styling (`style={{}}`) has been considered a bas practice for me.

In Mui V4 is was easy - I've just created a styles file and imported it to my component code using `makeStyles()` and `useStyles()` hooks.

Now with the new `sx` prop in Mui V5 I have no idea how to avoid inline styling. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar with sx too. Create a new styles file and define your objects there. Just use them in the `sx` attribute :

**styles.ts:**

```
const gridStyles = {
  backgroundColor: "blue",
  paddingBottom: 2,
  paddingRight: 2,
  marginTop: 2,
  marginLeft: "auto",
  marginRight: "auto",
  maxWidth: 500
};
export default gridStyles;
```

```
import gridStyles from './styles';

export default function FullWidthGrid() {
  return (
    <>
      <Grid
        container
        sx={gridStyles}
      </Grid>
  );
}
```

Comment: How would you apply a theme to this?

Comment: what if I want to style a normal html element such as <div> ( non mui component ) in MUI v4 I used to do everything with makestyles but now it seems like I should style html elements with plain css or  creating a whole new component for each html element with ''styled'' ? is there any better to style normal html elements ?

Comment: Answering @YassineSoltani's question, in case anyone else is wondering the same thing. This is straight from the MUI5 docs, "The Box component wraps your component. It creates a new DOM element, a <div> that by default can be changed with the component prop. Let's say you want to use a <span> instead". More examples can be found here: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-box/#overriding-mui-components

Answer (score 0):

to respond to @Yahli Gi, if u want to access the theme, there's two ways:

Method one:

```
const gridStyles = (theme) => ({
  backgroundColor: "blue",
  paddingBottom: 2,
  paddingRight: 2,
  marginTop:theme.spacing(1),
  marginLeft: "auto",
  marginRight: "auto",
  maxWidth: 500
});

export default gridStyles;
```

Method Two:

```
const gridStyles = {
  backgroundColor: "blue",
  paddingBottom: 2,
  paddingRight: 2,
  marginTop: (theme) => theme.spacing(1),
  marginLeft: "auto",
  marginRight: "auto",
  maxWidth: 500
};

export default gridStyles;
```

The imports are the same for the two examples above. Additionally the theme is automatically injected into the object by mui so no need to call the function yourself in the import.

```
import gridStyles from './styles';

export default function FullWidthGrid() {
  return (
    <>
      <Grid
        container
        sx={gridStyles}
      </Grid>
  );
}
```